# SBT Unresolved Dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

This is an SBT build file which I have written

```
name := "Introduction"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
    "releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
    )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.12.3" % "test")
```

when I run `sbt compile` I get error message

```
[info] Resolving org.specs2#spec2_2.11;1.12.3 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.specs2#spec2_2.11;1.12.3
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Abhishek\.ivy2\local\org.specs2\spec2_2.11\1.12.3\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/specs2/spec2_2.11/1.12.3/spec2_2.11-1.12.3.pom
[warn] ==== snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/specs2/spec2_2.11/1.12.3/spec2_2.11-1.12.3.pom
[warn] ==== releases: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/specs2/spec2_2.11/1.12.3/spec2_2.11-1.12.3.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.2/scala-library-2.11.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.2!scala-library.jar (1827ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.2/scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11.2!scala-compiler.jar (3875ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.2/scala-reflect-2.11.2.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.2!scala-reflect.jar (1375ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.specs2#spec2_2.11;1.12.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.specs2:spec2_2.11:1.12.3 (D:\myapps\Scala\hw\build.sbt#L12-13)
[warn]            +- introduction:introduction_2.11:1.0
```

Comment: That is quite the old specs2 version (2.5 years). It hasn't been published for scala 2.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" % "specs2_2.11.0-RC3" % "2.3.10"
```

Comment: base on your scala version, and search in maven repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2_2.11.0-RC3/2.3.10 : )

Comment: If so ... can I parameterize my scala version? so that if I am moving from 2.11 to 2.12 tomorrow I don't have to do a search and replace in my entire file?

Comment: I don't think it can work. because you don't know what have changed.

Comment: Yes you can, use `"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.10"`. Note the `%%`, that's what does that scala version part

Comment: This isn't the correct version :) You should have looked at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.specs2/specs2_2.11 instead. This way you can use `%% "specs2"` as normal. This one may happen to work, or it might have some subtle binary incompatibility.