# Unable to build Tensorflow for Scala using SBT (MacOS)

Tags: macos, scala, tensorflow, sbt

I am trying to include TensorFlow in my Scala project using [this](http://platanios.org/tensorflow_scala/index.html) build on MacOS.

As for the [installation](http://platanios.org/tensorflow_scala/installation.html) they provide two ways of doing so:

**1) Include the following line to the SBT build:**

`libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" % "tensorflow" % "0.4.0" classifier "darwin-cpu-x86_64"`

However this does not build and gives the following error:

`unresolved dependency: org.platanios#tensorflow;0.4.0: not found`

**2) Build TensorFlow from scratch** (which I did via the following steps):

- clone the tensorflow git repository
- checkout branch r1.12
- run `./configure`
- build using bazel and the following command: `bazel build --config=opt --cxxopt=-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so`
- add libtensorflow.so in a directory that is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- install protobuf using brew

However, still no success when I want to import tensorflow in my project.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: As per point 1) try and use `tensorflow_2.12` instead of just `tensorflow`

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot, you can put your solution as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Just curious, can you try this and see if it works? `libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" %% "tensorflow" % "0.4.0" classifier "darwin-cpu-x86_64"` So it's `%%`between the org and name instead of a single `%`.

Comment: Can you try `libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" % "tensorflow_2.12" % "0.4.0" classifier "darwin-cpu-x86_64"` or `libraryDependencies += "org.platanios" % "tensorflow_2.12" % "0.4.0"`

Comment: @KevinLee works as well, thanks.

Comment: @PabloLópezGallego yes this is the same approach suggested by mfirry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SBT Unresolved Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933258/sbt-unresolved-dependencies)

Comment: @Maarten What I said is the proper way to use any Scala library so if it's not a Java lib, better use `%%`. Then you don't need to change the version in the library name when you change your Scala version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the scala version (hopefully 2.12) so put  tensorflow_2.12 instead of just tensorflow